# Regex, word permutations and visual basic

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net, string

I have a wordlist text file, small in size, less than a few hundred words long. I want to take a keyword and check it against the wordlist, saving all of the matches and display them in a Listbox.

I am fairly new to programming, I have been looking into regex to match partial patterns, and have begun looking into creating a function to generate a list of every permutation/combination of the keyword and then run them against the wordlist.

I hope someone can help. I am hoping to ideally get a match on any word in the list that shares more than four letters in order (meaning, if the list has `stephen` and the keyword is `steph12345` then I want that to match. However `step_gtkyn0123` would pass through).

I am really just looking to be pointed in the right direction more than anything.

Comment: If you post some sample data, it could help people understand your problem better.

Comment: I guess we should post a meta-stack question asking moderators to use a special regex question posting page that asks everyone not to ask for parsing nested structures (XML, HTML, etc ..) and to have three sections for sample, input, output, what have you tried so far and what language are you using !!

Comment: i thought thought the title was clear on the lang but i'm sorry, the lang is visual basic.

Comment: it is a simple survey program that saves the input into a txt file on the local system, then asks for a keyword to test against the created file to see if a similar word exists. if it does the similar word is saved to a list box.  i am new to the reaching out for help from smarter people and willing to work teaching my self just looking for a helping hand not a comment fight.

Comment: Does the position of the match matter? Would 123steph123 be regarded as a match?

Comment: i would like it to match ideally.

Comment: while attempting to learn this on my own i came acrossed this, only i havent found much documentation explaining the code, so i havent done much with it yet.http://pastebin.com/Tv5StAmk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to find words that contain 5 or more consecutive letters from a specified keyword. The placement does not matter. Try the following:

```
 Dim words As String() = New String() {"steph", "steph123", "step_gtk", "stephan", "123steph123", "step1stph"}
 Dim keyword As String = "steph12345"
 'match must be greater than 4, so substring 5
 Dim rgx As String = keyword.Substring(0, 5)

 For Each word As String In words

     If Regex.IsMatch(word, rgx) Then
         Console.WriteLine(word)
     End If
 Next

'Outputs
'steph
'steph123
'stephan
'123steph123'
```

Comment: thank you i will toy around with this and see where it goes.